# Open Java SMB server implementation

Tags: java, samba, smb, cifs

Is there an open implementation of a SMB/CIFS server in Java? The only implementation I can find at all is Alfresco's but it isn't open source.

A related question: assuming there is no such implementation, I'm surprised there isn't a library providing even a subset of SMB e.g. for simple file transfer. My intuition is that it wouldn't be massively difficult to implement a simple server (but of course would be very difficult to implement a complete solution like Samba). The fact that no one seems to have done it makes me suspicious that it is harder than I'd guess. Is there no implementation because it is difficult or because no one cares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.alfresco.com/media/releases/2007/10/jlan1007/ JLAN is available under the GPL from sourceforge.net/projects/alfresco/files/ -- scroll down to the JLAN section at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, grabbed src and will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway looking at http://www.alfresco.com/products/aifs/ seem that they distribute it with dual licensing (no GPL mentioned) for developers and OEM...