# SMB/CIFS serverside implementation

Tags: c#, smb, cifs

Is there an opensource, preferrably fully managed smb/cifs implementation I could use to simulate a windows share from my server application? I would not have any folders/files locally on disk drive, but rather return content on request.

Comment: Check out Alfresco JLAN mentioned in the first answer to [Open Java SMB server implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854070/open-java-smb-server-implementation?rq=1). It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: ... with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) if you need to make it work in .net...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the `SMBLibrary` readme:

> SMBLibrary is an open-source C# SMB 1.0/CIFS, SMB 2.0 and SMB 2.1 server and client implementation.

https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary

It also allows you to share arbitrary data by implementing the `IFileSystem` interface.